# Excel index match with multiple criteria, both partial and exact match

Tags: excel, index-match, partial-matches

I am trying to find matches across two worksheets in Excel and return the value of an adjacent column. I can make this work fine using index match if I'm looking for an exact match, but I can't work out how to find a full match in one pair of columns, and a partial match in the other.

The formula I'm using is:
=INDEX('Worksheet B'!$C$2:$C$318,MATCH(1,COUNTIFS('Worksheet A'$A2,'Worksheet B'!$A$2:$A$318,'Worksheet A'$F2,'Worksheet B'!$B$2:$B$318),0))

which works fine for those columns where it's searching for an exact match. But say the column I'm searching in Worksheet B contains multiple values separated by comma delimiters, and the column in Worksheet A contains a single value - how do I search for the single value from worksheet A within the multiple values on worksheet B?

I've tried using `"*&'Worksheet A'!A2&"*"` but no joy. Am I barking up the wrong tree with index/match?

Here's the column with multiple values I'm trying to match. Apologies that I can't post more of the spreadsheet but it contains sensitive data.
[snip of spreadsheet column with multiple values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge3oW.png)

Many many thanks for any help and let me know if you need more info.

Comment: So, for instance, I only want to search for CL320354 in the first row and return the adjacent value in column C (not shown).

Comment: I am, yes! I will look up XMATCH now. Thank you!

Comment: I re-read your question and deleted my previous comment, it will actually lead you down the wrong road.  I dug into your formula and I am curious about your logic.  Is the INDEX formula in your question something that you paste down a column so that it repeats for A3, A4, etc and F3, F4, etc?  I would recommend a completely different approach that will be simpler, but I need to more precisely understand your logic.  Am I correct that if A2 and F2 both match a row in sheets A and B respectively, you just want the col. C value from that row in sheet B, even if there are multiple rows that match?

Comment: I'm happy to help, wondering if you are still looking for assistance with this.

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for updating this - I didn't resolve this and will need to come back to it at some point but don't have time at the moment and can't quite remember what exactly I was trying to do! I'll reply again when I'm back on it.